# Finding the index of the minimum value which is larger than a threshold in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This is probably very simple, but I'm missing the correct syntax in order to simplify it.

Given a matrix, find the entry in one column which is the lowest value, greater than some input parameter. Then, return an entry in a different column on that corresponding row. Not very complicated... and I've found something that *works* but, a more efficient solution would be greatly appreciated.

I found this link:[Better way to find a minimum value that fits a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595828/better-way-to-find-a-minimum-value-that-fits-a-condition)

which is great.. but that method of finding the least entry loses the index information required to find a corresponding value in a corresponding row.

Let's say column 2 is the condition column, and column 1 is the one I want to return.... currently I've made this: (note that this only works because row two is full of numbers which are less than 1).

```
matrix[which.max((matrix[,2]>threshhold)/matrix[,2]),1]
```

Any thoughts? I'm expecting that there is probably some quick and easy function which has this effect... it's just never been introduced to me haha.

Comment: What is wrong with a one-liner that solves your problem? However, this code fails if your cutoff is negative and there is a negative entry greater than the cutoff along with positive entries.

Comment: @JamesPringle I think one of my major considerations when looking for a "simpler" solution is that I'll be handing this code over to a successor very shortly. While this solution is concise, it's not immediately apparent why it works.

Comment: Well, that's what comments in code are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following. Say,

```
df <- matrix(sample(1:35,35),7,5)
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   18   16   27   19   31
[2,]   24    1    7   12    5
[3,]   28   35   23    4    6
[4,]   33    3   25   26   15
[5,]   14   10   11   21   20
[6,]    9    2   32   17   13
[7,]   30    8   29   22   34
```

Say your threshold is 5:

```
apply(df,2,function(x){ x[x<5] <- max(x);which.min(x)})
[1] 6 7 2 2 2
```

Corresponding to the values:

```
[1]  9  8  7 12  5
```

This should give you the index of the smallest entry in each column greater than threshold according to the original column indexing.

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong inequality direction. Now corrected to "less than"

Comment: I noticed that, may not still be 100% correct however though. Should it be "`x[x<=5]` seeing as it returns 5 as a result.

Comment: This returns entries from each column. Is there a way that simplifies it even further to only consider entries in one row?

Comment: @jameselmore: So, you want the column index with the minimum value (above a threshold) for each row?

Comment: in the best case scenario, it would hunt ONE column for the minimum value (above a threshold) and then return a value in a different column corresponding to the row which contained the minimum value above that threshold. I was interested in the index of that column because I could just plug that into the column of which I want the result to return from... if that makes sense

Comment: Then @Carl Witthoft's answer should work for you. It gives you the corresponding value in output column (`outcol`) for the minimum (above `threshold`) value in a selected column (`incol`).

Answer (score 4):

rmk's answer shows the basic way to get a lot of info out of your matrix.  But if you know which column you're testing for the minimum value (above your threshold), and then want to return a different value in that row, maybe something like

```
incol<- df[,4] # select the column to search
outcol <- 2 # select the element of the found row you want to get
threshold <- 5
df[ rev(order(incol>threshold))[1] ,outcol]
```

Comment: Does this solution assume that there is at least one number in incol that is greater than the threshold?

Comment: @Henrik Yeah, I think it does, so it might be worth putting in an `if` to make sure there's a value to be grabbed in the first place.